# Manejo de estructuras. Como crear una dentro de otra

Tags: c

Quiero que el usuario agregue los datos de los libros y luego guardarlos en la biblioteca. ¿Algún consejo para trabajar con dos estructuras? Les dejo lo que avancé hasta ahora.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

//Estructura del libro.
typedef struct{
   char titulo[100];
   char genero[100;
   int paginas;
   int anio_de_edicion;
   char numero_isbn[100];
   char editorial[100];
}Libros;

//Estructura de biblioteca.
typedef struct{
   int Libros vec[100];
}Biblioteca[100];

//Funcion para agregar libros.
void alta(Libros * m){
    printf("Titulo: ");
    gets(m->titulo);
    printf("genero: ");
    gets(m->genero);
    printf("paginas: ");
    scanf("%d", m->&paginas);
    printf("año de edicion: ");
    scanf("%d", m->&anio_de_edicion);
    printf("numero isbn: ");
    gets(m->numero_isbn);
    printf("editorial: ");
    gets(m->editorial);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos cosas importantes cuando trabajas con estructuras que no debes confundir: definir una estructura y declarar una estructura.

Al definir una estructura, lo que haces es crear un nuevo tipo de dato (equivalente a int, char o cualquier otro que el compilador ya conozca).

Declarar una estructura, es reservar espacio en memoria para una (o mas) estructuras que ya fueron definidas previamente.

Es importante que entiendas que una estructura es 100% equivalente a cualquier otro tipo de dato estandar de C, y por lo tanto puedes declarar estructuras individualmente, array de estructuras, punteros a estructuras, o cualquier otra cosa que normalmente haces con los otros tipos de datos.

Esta es tu definición de la estructura libro:

```
typedef struct{
   char titulo[100];
   char genero[100;
   int paginas;
   int anio_de_edicion;
   char numero_isbn[100];
   char editorial[100];
}Libros;
```

Y está perfectamente hecha, no hay nada para agregar (recuerda que con esto no estas declarando ninguna variable, no hay espacio en memoria reservado para ningun libro)

Ahora, para crear la biblioteca, no tienes ninguna necesidad de definir una nueva estructura, ya que la biblioteca simplemente será un conjunto de libros y por lo tanto, con que declares un array de libros será suficiente, eso debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Libros biblioteca[100];

Ahora tendrás un array (o vector) llamado biblioteca donde habrá espacio para 100 Libros.

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No hay por que, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te dejo algunos consejos para tus proximas preguntas o participaciones en el foro. Puedes realizar el [tour] y leer [ask] para entender un poco la dinámica del sitio y el tipo de preguntas que se esperan. Este no es un foro clásico: la idea es que las preguntas tengan un ejemplo [mcve]. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, si tenés otra pregunta, en lugar de hacerla aca en los comentarios, te conviene crear una nueva pregunta en la página. Te va a resultar mas fácil para ingresar el código y además puede ayudarle a otras personas en el futuro.